# How to solve NoMethodError in RailsAdmin::Main#index?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

When I try to use Rails Admin for articles. I'm getting the following error.
[This Image shows you the error I am facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFhgY.png)

Here is articles_controller.rb

```html
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_article, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_auth_user!, except: [:index, :show]
  # GET /articles
  # GET /articles.json
  def index
    @articles=Article.all
  end

  # GET /articles/1
  # GET /articles/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /articles/new
  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  # GET /articles/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /articles
  # POST /articles.json
  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @article.save
        format.html { redirect_to @article, notice: 'Article was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @article }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /articles/1
  # PATCH/PUT /articles/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @article.update(article_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @article, notice: 'Article was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @article }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /articles/1
  # DELETE /articles/1.json
  def destroy
    @article.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to articles_url, notice: 'Article was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_article
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
      @comments = @article.comments.all
      @comment = @article.comments.build
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title, :meta_description, :description, :category_id, :video)
    end
end
```

And here is article.rb file in model

```html
class Article
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  has_many :comments
  belongs_to :category

  field :title, type: String
  field :meta_description, type: String
  field :description, type: String
  field :category_id, type: String
  field :video, type: String
end
```

Here is my gemfile

```html
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "2.3.1"

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0', '>= 5.0.0.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.6'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'mongoid', '~>6.0.3'
gem 'carrierwave-mongoid', :require => 'carrierwave/mongoid'
gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.2'
gem 'devise', '~> 4.2'
gem 'mail_form', '~> 1.6'
gem 'ckeditor', '~> 4.2'
gem 'rails_admin', '~> 1.1'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', '~> 3.2', '>= 3.2.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.2.0.2'
gem 'less-rails', '~> 2.8'
gem 'therubyracer', '~> 0.12.2'
gem 'mongoid-ancestry', '~> 0.4.2'
gem 'simple_form', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.1'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development
group :production do
  gem 'pg', '~> 0.19.0'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '~> 0.0.3'
end
group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

comment.rb

```html
class Comment
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  belongs_to :article
  field :name, type: String
  field :email, type: String
  field :article_id, type: String
  field :comment, type: String
end
```

category.rb

```html
class Category
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Ancestry
  has_many :articles
  has_ancestry
  mount_uploader :image, FileUploader
  field :name, type: String
  field :image, type: String
  field :parent_id, type: String
end
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: yes the comment and category models are properly setup

Comment: Can you post your `Comment` and `Category` models? By the way, you can remove the `Gemfile` and `ArticlesController` from your question. They have nothing to do with the error you're getting.

Comment: Ok I will post them

Comment: The models look fine to me except in `Comment` model where you have a field named `comment` too. Can you post the code in `MainController`?

Comment: I have notices some thing when I remove     belongs_to :category from Article model. The active admin is working fine.